# Does Andy emulator respond to computer keyboard while playing Android games?

Tags: android-emulator, external-keyboard, emulators

I'm using Windows 8 Pro in Dell laptop. I want to know, is there a way to assign the computer keyboard to the Android games? Screen tapping by the mouse is not enough to have the full control in the game e.g. [Temple run](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun), so I need help: Does Andy emulator respond to computer keyboard while playing Android games?

Answer (score 1):

Try the <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> keys or the <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd> combinations in your keyboard. This should work for you.

For swipe functionalities use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with arrow keys combination,

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> ->  Swipe towards Right
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> ->  Swipe towards Left